# Prevent some indexes to be shared with other nodes in Elasticsearch 1.7.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm sharing different indexes with different nodes in Elasticsearch 1.7.x. However, I was wondering whether it's possible not to share some of these indexes and keep them only in certain nodes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, basically an index is combination of its shards.

> A shard is a single Lucene instance. It is a low-level “worker” unit which is managed automatically by elasticsearch. An index is a logical namespace which points to primary and replica shards. Other than defining the number of primary and replica shards that an index should have, you never need to refer to shards directly. Instead, your code should deal only with an index. Elasticsearch distributes shards amongst all nodes in the cluster, and can move shards automatically from one node to another in the case of node failure, or the addition of new nodes.

You can set shard allocation by index

```
PUT test/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.include._ip": "192.168.2.*"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know whether it's possible to remove previously allocated shards in a node?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and this is another question soI am adding this as solution,

You can use the [Cluster Reroute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html) function, I think the example is self explanatory.

Example from the documentation:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
    "commands" : [ {
        "move" :
            {
              "index" : "test", "shard" : 0,
              "from_node" : "node1", "to_node" : "node2"
            }
        },
        {
          "allocate" : {
              "index" : "test", "shard" : 1, "node" : "node3"
          }
        }
    ]
}'
```